# How to restart a Celery Worker in Airflow

Tags: bash, docker, celery, airflow, flower

I'm currently running into an issue where my Celery worker freezes once in a while and needs to be restarted. I have an instance of Airflow from which I would like to configure and schedule a restart using the `BashOperator` or `SSHOperator`, but I'm not sure how to proceed since it's in a Docker container.

From the localhost I would just "docker restart worker", but since Bash operates inside the airflow container I need to find a way to restart via the airflow CLI or SSH from the container to the host, which sounds terrible. Is there an elegant way to approach this?

**EDIT:** I see that Flower has a REST API from which I can restart the pool, but I have to have that enabled in my celery config. It looks like [airflow is setting the config](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/executors/celery_executor.py) already, is there any way to override this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is what I ended up doing:

```
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id="celery_restart",
    bash_command="celery multi restart 1",
    dag=dag
)
```

Doesn't really stop my tasks from hanging, but there it is :).